# How to open a Protected word document using Openoffice api with java?

Tags: java, apache, openoffice.org

I am trying to open ".docx" document using open office but i am not getting how to open a password protected ".docx" file using open office java api.

please suggest me what properties i have to use to access password protedted ".docx" file.

When i try to open with below property values, i got IllegalArgumentException

```
     PropertyValue[] loadProps = new PropertyValue[3];
        loadProps[0] = new PropertyValue(); 
        loadProps[0].Name = "FilterName"; 
        loadProps[0].Value = "StarOffice XML (Writer)"; 
        loadProps[1] = new PropertyValue();
        loadProps[1].Name = "PassWord";
        loadProps[1].Value = "abcdef";
    Object objectDocumentToStore = xcomponentloader.loadComponentFromURL(loadUrl, "_default", 0, loadProps);
```

Exception

```
com.sun.star.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL seems to be an unsupported one.
at com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.Job.remoteUnoRequestRaisedException(Job.java:180)
at com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.Job.execute(Job.java:146)
at com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.JobQueue.enter(JobQueue.java:338)
at com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.JobQueue.enter(JobQueue.java:307)
at com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.JavaThreadPool.enter(JavaThreadPool.java:94)
at com.sun.star.lib.uno.bridges.java_remote.java_remote_bridge.sendRequest(java_remote_bridge.java:642)
at com.sun.star.lib.uno.bridges.java_remote.ProxyFactory$Handler.request(ProxyFactory.java:154)
at com.sun.star.lib.uno.bridges.java_remote.ProxyFactory$Handler.invoke(ProxyFactory.java:136)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.loadComponentFromURL(Unknown Source)
at com.pravridh.puneeth.DocumentToPdfWithFilterData.main(DocumentToPdfWithFilterData.java:49)
```

Answer (score 0):

just write this code to open documents

```
String cmds[] = new String[] {"cmd", "/c",
     "C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\EA01.pdf"};
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmds);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(secretry.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```